# Swift 3 Filter Json & Reorder

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a little Problem in Swift with a Json Source.

In one Tableview I get the Json Source:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://url")!
        let urlSession = URLSession.shared

        let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            let jsonData =  try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject]
            //adressiere Array in JSON Dictionary
            self.Devs = jsonData?["devices"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
```

I the didSelectRowAt section I let the user select rows and the IDs of the Json is added to an UserDefault array.

in the First ViewController I have the same Json code as above but I filter it with the UserDefault array:

devArray is the array containing the IDs that the user selected.

```
let jsonData =  try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject]

            //adressiere Array in JSON Dictionary
            self.Devs = jsonData?["devices"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]

            //Filter Array
            let filterarray = self.devArray
            self.filteredArray = self.Devs.filter { filterarray.contains($0["id"] as! String) }
```

This first Viewcontroller has a CollectionView and I already implemented the functions to reorder the Cells:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath,
                        to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        // TODO: Update data model to reflect the change
        let temp = devArray[sourceIndexPath.row]

        devArray[sourceIndexPath.row] = devArray[destinationIndexPath.row]
        devArray[destinationIndexPath.row] = temp

    }
```

This reorders the devArray, and it works.(i print it to the console)
But as soon as I refresh the view, it goes back and orders itself in the order the Ids come from the json source.
I have to pull the Json because I need values from the json source that change.

Does anyone have an idea? I hope I described my problem right ;-)

My cellForItemAt:

```
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let colcel = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    let devListItem = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
    //Attribute
    let devListValue = (devListItem["attributes"]?.value(forKey: "value"))
    let resultDevListValue = String(describing: devListValue!)


    //Cell Text & Color & See if it is a Switch
    if (devListItem["template"]?.contains("switch"))! {
        if resultDevListValue.contains("0") {
            colcel.topLabel.text = devListItem["name"] as? String

        } else {
            colcel.topLabel.text = devListItem["name"] as? String
        }
    } else {
        //print("kein switch")
    }

    return colcel
}
```

Comment: can you also post cellForItemAtIndexPath method? You might be accessing your data source incorrectly

Comment: I inserted the method above

Comment: Check my answer, it might be the cause of your problem. As a side note, I strongly suggest to create model object for "dev" and use that instead of array of dictionaries you get from JSON parser. It will be much easier to maintain and use in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building your cells based on filteredArray in cellForItemAt method:

```
let devListItem = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
```

but when you move cell, you update devArray

```
let temp = devArray[sourceIndexPath.row]
devArray[sourceIndexPath.row] = devArray[destinationIndexPath.row]
devArray[destinationIndexPath.row] = temp
```

I assume those are two different arrays. You need to use same array in both places or sync them when you move cells

Comment: devArray is the array holding the id's that the user selected, filteredArray is the result from the json source which only contains the response to the ids in devArray, so unfortunately this doesnt work.  I think the problem is the sorting of the json, because I always have to get it from the source. I might need to find a way to sort the json on the server and load it then.

Comment: You definitely don't need to sort anything on the server. I don't know how are you creating devArray, but it's not JSON anymore, it is parsed data from the JSON, you should be able to do anything with it. The problem in the code you posted is that you don't sort the array you use to populate your cells with, you are reordering different array

Comment: You are right I think I have an idea:  I have an array which has the ids in the right order  and I could sort the Collectionview with this array, I just have to find a way to do this...

Comment: you can find correct Id by looking into devArray, like this: let id = devArray[indexPath.row] and use this id to search filteredArray for correct object (let item = filteredArray.filter { $0["id"] == id }[0] or something like this, it's not very robust). Or you could update order of things in the filteredArray in moveItemAt method, same way you are updating order of items in devArray